# Zend Framework 2 Authentication

Tags: authentication, zend-framework2

I have a conceptual question.
Working on a site for a client. Very simple site. Kind of a mini CMS, almost every section is database driven. My thought is rather than having the main site and then a separate section for editing, I would check for authentication and have the admin user edit the section directly.

My question is, where should that authentication happen? Is it possible/efficient to check from the controller? Or should I check it at the module?

I am using zfcUser (if that makes any difference)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have two routes. One to get the page and all the sections with content from the database. Another route should be created for updating the content.

When you have two routes, you have probably also two actions. And perhaps even two controllers. With `Zend\Permission\Acl` or `Zend\Permission\Rbac` you can "protect" the one route, or action, or controller where you update the content.

If you want an easier integration of ZfcUser and ACL, use [BjyAuthorize](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize). If you prefer to use RBAC, you are better off with [ZfcRbac](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcRbac).

Comment: Actually, the reading and updating I have down... and I can do either from one place (same controller) - my problem is how do I access zfcUser from the controller? Or, is that even a good idea? Should I do it from the module? I won't "protect" a controller, but individual sections in the view (<div>s). I just don't want to have to check for identity in every view. There SHOULD be a way to check that at controller level.

Comment: If you need the `User` entity in your controller, that's an entirely different question. There is a ZfcUser authentication service from which you can grab the user identity. But before you have that identity, you really need to take care of authorisation first (so use either ACL or RBAC).